# Query for a list of string with like

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a table `Document` with some columns e.g. `DocumentTitle`. Looks like this:

---

*Document*

- Id (uniqueidentifier)
- DocumentTitle (varchar(200))

---

in my application you enter a string you search for like "invoice 4711". Now my application shall search for all documents where both of these words are in the title. 
So documents with title `foo4711.pdf`, `invoice_bar.pdf` won't be found.
Documents with title `invoce 4711.pdf` or `test4711invoce.png`shall be found.

Since i write this in a procedure i can't set a fix parameter-count for searchstrings. I'm getting one parameter e.g. `invoice 4711` and my split-method returns a table with all items like (and yes, with the %-signs)

---

*items*

%4711%

%invoice%

---

Sooo when I try now to get all Documents where both of those values match I get a wrong result (but, yes it makes always sense :D )

***info***: the fn_split- function takes the searchstring as first parameter and the second parameter is the sliced sign

```
select * 
from document 
WHERE 1 = (
    select case 
        when document.documenttitle like items then 1 else 0 end 
    from fn_split('invoice 4711', ' ') 
    where document.documenttitle like items
);
```

---

```
select * 
from document 
inner join fn_split('invoice 4711', ' ') 
on document.DocumentTitle like items
```

---

both of these queries returns the result where any of those words are contained - not both.
Any idea what the issue is here? or how the query works right?

Comment: First the data structure to have a proper junction table for the items.

Comment: Hi, what u have to search is: %4711%invoice% and %invoice%4711%, so u have to modify your split function in a "scrumbler" function. U should try something similar to Select items + '%' from fn_split('invoice 4711', ' ')  a, fn_split('invoice 4711', ' ')  b Where a.items <> b.items for xml path('')

Comment: @GigiS what if 'invoice 4711 John Smith Texas' ?

Comment: @Serg:  'invoice 4711 John Smith Texas'  is matched by %invoice%4711%

Comment: but would not match '4711 invoice'??

Comment: if u have to search the phrases containing the words 4711 and invoice, u need a function that returns two rows: the first  %4711%invoice%, the second %invoice%4711%. U can do that with cross joins + for xml path (to serialize)

Comment: Yes, but with 4 or 5 strings the list of possibilities gets really long.. the solution of Serg works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count them.

```
declare @arg varchar(100) ='invoice 4711';
select * 
from document
cross apply ( 
select n=count(*) from fn_split(@arg, ' ') x where
 document.DocumentTitle like x.items) cnt
where (select count(*) from fn_split(@arg, ' ')) = cnt.n;
```